# Deserialize list of lists with multiple types using Gson

Tags: json, list, gson

I think I've searched the entire internet looking for this one.
I'm new to Java and writing an app that uses an API from a server that I do not control.
This server gives back Json in a way that has to be the least straight forward when trying to deserialize.

For a certain call I get this:

```
{"error":[],"result":{"XETHZUSD":[[1494507600,"90.17924","90.20000","89.00000","89.01731","89.63742","1980.59102620",387],[1494511200,"89.01731","89.68989","89.00000","89.08521","89.18840","309.22705599",90]],"last":1494507600}}
```

My issue is with the "list of lists" that's returned inside of the `result` object, the inner-most list is of multiple types (`longs` and `Strings`)

I don't know how to retrieve these values... 
The classes I have setup are:

```
public class Response {

     @SerializedName("error")
     @Expose
     public List<String> error = null;

}

public class OHLCResponse extends Response{

     @SerializedName("result")
     @Expose
     public OHLCResult result;
}

public class OHLCResult {
    @SerializedName("XETCZUSD")
    @Expose
    public List<List<XXX>> XETCZUSD = null;

   @SerializedName("last")
   @Expose
   public Long last; 
}
```

Also, I don't know what `@Expose` does... I used [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) site to look at the API results and make some classes for me, it had `@Expose` in there so I left it.

Where **XXX** is above, is what I don't know what should go here. I can't just create a list without a type. I tried making it a list of a list of `Object` but that doesn't work either, I get:

`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 35 path $.result.XETHZUSD`

Any help would be appreciated. I've read a ton before posting this but I couldn't find anything close enough to my example to use.

Thanks!

EDIT: The other caveat to this is that in the `result` object, the list of lists is called `XETHZUSD` but this name could be any currency pair depending on your call to the server.
Is there a way to handle this without having to explicitly add a list of lists for every possible return value?

Comment: You could use object as the type: as shown on [this site](http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/) if you try and generate a java class based on your json string. You're practically forced to use object, since they mix numbers and strings.

Comment: So then what do I do with the Objects after?

Comment: loop through every object in the list of list of objects and call `.toString()` on each object. Or parse the first and last object to an integer and every object inbetween to a string. The last option requires the json to stay the same format at all times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main rule here is: just don't trust automatic generators:

- Say, `1494507600` looks definitely like a value of seconds since January 1, 1970, the Unix epoch begin.
- `XETCZUSD` looks pretty much like a dynamic code, and not a real name (your JSON and your mappings differ by the way, too)
- Arrays, like those that are inner ones, are just plain values. You have to discover it real meanings, but anyway, no tool is so intelligent to map an array-like value to a mapping.

Knowing all of that, you have to perform at least a few steps to make your response be *convenient regardless the amount of code you have to implement to let it be convenient*.

### Phase 1: Define your mappings

#### OHLCResponse.java

```
final class OHLCResponse {

    final List<String> error = null;
    final OHLCResult result = null;

}
```

#### OHLCResult.java

```
final class OHLCResult {

    final String code;
    final List<OHLCUnknown> values;
    final Date last;

    OHLCResult(final String code, final List<OHLCUnknown> values, final Date last) {
        this.code = code;
        this.values = values;
        this.last = last;
    }

}
```

#### OHLCUnknown.java

This one is weird, but you can investigate what it covers. If possible, of course.

```
final class OHLCUnknown {

    final Date unknownDate;
    final List<String> unknownStrings;
    final Long unknownNumber;

    OHLCUnknown(final Date unknownDate, final List<String> unknownStrings, final Long unknownNumber) {
        this.unknownDate = unknownDate;
        this.unknownStrings = unknownStrings;
        this.unknownNumber = unknownNumber;
    }

}
```

### Phase 2: Write type adapters

This is the most complex phase, but again: it's **worthy** for the efforts.

#### TypeTokens.java

Type tokens are used to identify the *exact* Java type (NOT class!) including the type and it's generic parameterization.
Type tokens are immutable and you can consider them effective constants to be reused.

```
final class TypeTokens {

    private TypeTokens() {
    }

    static final TypeToken<List<OHLCUnknown>> ohlcUnknownListTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<OHLCUnknown>>() {
    };

    static final TypeToken<Date> dateTypeToken = new TypeToken<Date>() {
    };

}
```

#### AbstractReadOnlyTypeAdapter.java

It looks like you're not going to write back, so you can just suppress the write operation and not let it to be overridden in subclasses.

```
abstract class AbstractReadOnlyTypeAdapter<T>
        extends TypeAdapter<T> {

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public final void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

#### DateTypeAdapter.java

The simplest type adapter that just converts a long value to a date.
Really straight-forward.
Also note that the constructor is private not letting any caller to instantiate the date type adapter.
Why?
Because `TypeAdapter<T>` allows to wrap null-safe adapters, and we can instantiate the adapter globally once, but not letting any caller to know how we obtain the type adapter instance.

```
final class DateTypeAdapter
        extends AbstractReadOnlyTypeAdapter<Date> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter = new DateTypeAdapter().nullSafe();

    private DateTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<Date> getDateTypeAdapter() {
        return dateTypeAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public Date read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        return new Date(in.nextLong() * 1000L);
    }

}
```

#### OHLCResultTypeAdapterFactory.java

This one is more complex, but it's easy to understand the idea: just read the current JSON stream value.
Note that you have to use `TypeAdapterFactory`, not `TypeAdapter` directly, because you have to obtain *existing* type adapters from the `Gson` instance.
First, check if the type, represented using the type token, is `OHLCResult`, and if not, then return `null` telling Gson try to pick the first-best type adapter.
If the class is `OHLCResult`, then just build the appropriate type adapter, and "deconstruct" the incoming JSON stream token by token: `{`, `name`, `XXXXXXXX`, `} .

```
final class OHLCResultTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory ohlcResultTypeAdapterFactory = new OHLCResultTypeAdapterFactory();

    private OHLCResultTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getOhlcResultTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return ohlcResultTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !OHLCResult.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<List<OHLCUnknown>> ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(ohlcUnknownListTypeToken);
        final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(dateTypeToken);
        final TypeAdapter<OHLCResult> ohlcResultTypeAdapter = new OHLCResultTypeAdapter(ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter, dateTypeAdapter).nullSafe();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) ohlcResultTypeAdapter;
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    private static final class OHLCResultTypeAdapter
            extends AbstractReadOnlyTypeAdapter<OHLCResult> {

        private static final Pattern dynamicNamePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{8}");

        private final TypeAdapter<List<OHLCUnknown>> ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter;
        private final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter;

        private OHLCResultTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<List<OHLCUnknown>> ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter, final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter) {
            this.ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter = ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter;
            this.dateTypeAdapter = dateTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public OHLCResult read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();
            String code = null;
            List<OHLCUnknown> valueDynamic = null;
            Date valueLast = null;
            while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                final String name = in.nextName();
                switch ( name ) {
                case "last":
                    valueLast = dateTypeAdapter.read(in);
                    break;
                default:
                    final Matcher matcher = dynamicNamePattern.matcher(name);
                    if ( matcher.matches() ) {
                        code = name;
                        valueDynamic = ohlcUnknownListTypeAdapter.read(in);
                        break;
                    }
                    throw new MalformedJsonException("Unrecognized: " + name + " at " + in);
                }
            }
            in.endObject();
            return new OHLCResult(code, valueDynamic, valueLast);
        }

    }

}
```

#### OHLCUnknownTypeAdapterFactory.java

This type adapter factory works similar to the above one, but it just deconstructs the incoming JSON stream using another strategy.

```
final class OHLCUnknownTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final OHLCUnknownTypeAdapterFactory ohlcUnknownTypeAdapterFactory = new OHLCUnknownTypeAdapterFactory();

    private OHLCUnknownTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static OHLCUnknownTypeAdapterFactory getOhlcUnknownTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return ohlcUnknownTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !OHLCUnknown.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(dateTypeToken);
        final TypeAdapter<OHLCUnknown> ohlcUnknownTypeAdapter = new OHLCUnknownTypeAdapter(dateTypeAdapter).nullSafe();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) ohlcUnknownTypeAdapter;
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    private static final class OHLCUnknownTypeAdapter
            extends AbstractReadOnlyTypeAdapter<OHLCUnknown> {

        private final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter;

        private OHLCUnknownTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter) {
            this.dateTypeAdapter = dateTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public OHLCUnknown read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            in.beginArray();
            final Date unknownDate = dateTypeAdapter.read(in);
            final List<String> unknownStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            while ( in.peek() == JsonToken.STRING ) {
                unknownStrings.add(in.nextString());
            }
            final Long unknownNumber = in.nextLong();
            in.endArray();
            return new OHLCUnknown(unknownDate, unknownStrings, unknownNumber);
        }

    }

}
```

### Phase 3: Use it

Now you have to configure your `Gson` instance by registering appropriate type adapters and type adapter factories.
Note the difference between them here.

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, getDateTypeAdapter())
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getOhlcResultTypeAdapterFactory())
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getOhlcUnknownTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
```

`response.json` below just contains the JSON you posted in the question:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43919891.class, "response.json") ) {
        final OHLCResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, OHLCResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response.result.last);
        System.out.println(response.result.code);
        for ( final OHLCUnknown ohlcUnknown : response.result.values ) {
            System.out.println("*\t" + ohlcUnknown.unknownDate);
            System.out.println("\t" + ohlcUnknown.unknownStrings);
            System.out.println("\t" + ohlcUnknown.unknownNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Thu May 11 16:00:00 EEST 2017
>   XETHZUSD
>   *  Thu May 11 16:00:00 EEST 2017
>     [90.17924, 90.20000, 89.00000, 89.01731, 89.63742, 1980.59102620]
>     387
>   *  Thu May 11 17:00:00 EEST 2017
>     [89.01731, 89.68989, 89.00000, 89.08521, 89.18840, 309.22705599]
>     90

Of course, you can redesign your mappings and improve them.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for taking the time. I'll be going through this more closely to make sure I understand it before using.. really appreciate it!